# ModelForm required=True not behaving as expected

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using Django 1.11

I'm not getting the behaviour I'd expect from the [ModelForm docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types)...

> In addition, each generated form field has attributes set as follows:
>
> If the model field has blank=True, then required is set to False on
>   the form field. Otherwise, required=True.

I'm using a ModelForm:

```
class TestForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CUser
        fields = '__all__'
```

And the underlying model:

```
class CUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
    a_t = models.BooleanField()
```

But my form field a_t does not have the required=True setting set.
(I know I can create the field in the form to make this work, but I'm curious as to why this isn't working the way (that I understand) it should)

What am I missing?

Edit:

I also have this in my model:

```
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name','last_name']
```

But [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types) also say that this shouldn't effect things...

> REQUIRED_FIELDS has no effect in other parts of Django, like creating a user in the admin.

Comment: I guess this is a copy error, but your model doesn't inherit from models.Model :)

Comment: Yes, I was rewriting for brevity. Edited to fix.

Comment: @user2726394 give more clarification.

Comment: @nawarkhede Umm, what should I clarify? The form that is generated doesn't require the checkbox to be checked, as would be expected. Checking .required on the field returns False

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#booleanfield) `forms.BooleanField` by default (when empty) returns `False`. 
Also `models.BooleanField` can be only `True` or `False` - so it by **default** requires some value.
**UPDATE** I have found in the source code of BooleanField (Django 1.11):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['blank'] = True
    super(BooleanField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I think this means that **by default** Django set `blank=True` for each `BooleanField`. 
**UPDATE 2** Looks like it has been even changed in **[Django 2.0](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py) - 1020 line**:

```
def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        if self.choices:
            include_blank = not (self.has_default() or 'initial' in kwargs)
            defaults = {'choices': self.get_choices(include_blank=include_blank)}
        else:
            form_class = forms.NullBooleanField if self.null else forms.BooleanField
            # In HTML checkboxes, 'required' means "must be checked" which is
            # different from the choices case ("must select some value").
            # required=False allows unchecked checkboxes.
            defaults = {'form_class': form_class, 'required': False}
        return super().formfield(**{**defaults, **kwargs})
```

P.S. As you see in the commented lines - that is exactly what I was talking about, almost word to word :D

Comment: Okay, but the first line from the docs that I gave says that unless the model fields has blank=True, then the form field attribute 'required' will be set to True. This is not the case. The form field attribute 'required' is set to false.

Comment: What do you mean? Model's BooleanField has no `blank=True`. That field has no this attribute.

Comment: A ModelForm generates a Form from a model, creating a Form field for every Model field specified in the ModelForm Meta 'fields' list. The documentation says that each generated Form field will have required=True (Unless the Model field has blank=True). My Form field is not being set to required=True as I would expect.

Comment: Logically `required = True` means: **u have to put some value in this field**. If BooleanField has `required = true` - does that mean it always should be selected? And may be it does not have `require = True` because it anyway will receive some value - eigther `default` or `selected`? That just my thoughts about this problem.

Comment: No, that's not the behaviour for a required Boolean field.I can create a BooleanField in the form manually and set required=True. This does several things: 1)Widgets of required form fields have the required HTML attribute. 2)The form validates that the checkbox is selected. **I just want to know why the code is not behaving as described in the docs**

Comment: Can you show the exact line in the docs u are referring to? Cuz I cant find that.

Comment: It's the exact line I quoted in my original question: "In addition, each generated form field has attributes set as follows:

If the model field has blank=True, then required is set to False on the form field. Otherwise, required=True."

Comment: Seems I have found the cause of the problem :) See update.

Answer (score 0):

I've never gotten this to work with a `BooleanField`. But it works with an `IntegerField` just fine. Something like:

```
YESNO_CHOICES = (
    (0, 'no'),
    (1, 'yes'),
)

a_t = models.IntegerField(default=1, choices=YESNO_CHOICES)
```